# How to apply a previously unseen image to a previously saved model?

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I wanted to know how to apply a previously unseen image to a previously saved CNN model and see how it classifies it ?

## Code (My attempt)

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

img_path = '/Users/eoind/code/1.jpg'

model = load_model('food.h5')
model.summary()

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(100,100))
image = image.img_to_array(img)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
print(image.shape)

images = np.vstack([image])

print("classifying images..")
image_class = model.predict_classes(images)
print(image_class)
```

## iPython Console Error

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 100, 100, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the input shape of your network does not match the shape of your image. It seems like the first layer of your network is a `dense` layer, which is a *fully-connected* layer and it expects the input to be of shape `(batch_size, num_of_neurons_in_the_bottom)`, but your are giving it an image with shape `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. Here is a checklist for troubleshooting your problem:

- Has the model at least loaded? If the above error happens during loading, then your model is broken (perhaps not properly saved). If not, continue through the checklist...
- In programming, *always output the values of your variables for debugging!* What is the value of `model.summary()`? Are you sure that the input shape of your network is `(100, 100, 3)`? Is the first layer a *convolutional* one?
- If the first layer is `dense` (which is *fully-connected*), check the training code on how you feed images to the model - maybe your image should be re-shaped or somehow pre-processed?